# Activated state checked programmatically in an adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, state

I've a Menu Drawer with a ListView and in it's adapter I inflate a custom layout in getView();
now the background of the ListView item is a drawable selector with a particular drawable for the "activated" state: it is used correctly both when the first element of the list is activated programmatically and when pressed by the user. 
My problem is that I want to change the TypeFace of a TextView programmatically with setTypeFace() in the getView, but if I call isActivated() on the view passed to the getView() method it returns true when the item is selected by the user but false when it is selected programmatically.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: are you saying that `View.setActivated()` doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your comment, the answer is no, View.setActivated() doesn't work.